# wordpress Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Tags: php, wordpress

I keep getting this error but I'm pretty sure nothing's wrong with my code:
**EDIT: The error also says Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$0 in**

```
<?php foreach ($testoppervlaktes as $oppervlakte): ?>
                    <?php 
                    foreach($testtypes as $key => $value){
                        if($oppervlakte[$value->$key == true]){                       

                        } else {               

                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <option data-4="" data-5="" data-6="" data-7="" value="<?php echo $oppervlakte->name ?>"<?php if(isset($_GET['oppervlakte']) && $_GET['oppervlakte'] == $oppervlakte): ?> selected<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $oppervlakte->name; ?></option>
```

the error is on this line

> if($oppervlakte[$value->$key == true]){

everything else of my code works I keep getting this error in my html

I did a

> var_dump($oppervlakte);

and from the result:

```
object(stdClass)#4290 (11) {
["term_id"]=>
string(2) "23"
["name"]=>
string(16) "5000m2 - 10000m2"
["slug"]=>
string(14) "5000m2-10000m2"
["term_group"]=>
string(1) "0"
["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
string(2) "23"
["taxonomy"]=>
string(11) "oppervlakte"
["description"]=>
string(0) ""
["parent"]=>
string(1) "0"
["count"]=>
string(1) "2"
["6"]=>
bool(true)
["4"]=>
bool(true)
}
```

I want to check if the ["6"] and ["4"] is true but there could be more or less fields that are true or false it can be ["4"] ["5"] ["6"] ["7"] all false/true or mixed

in an earlier loop I set the data to true or false

```
foreach($testoppervlaktes as $key => $value){
        if($value->term_id == $huidigvastgoedoppervlakteid){
            $testoppervlaktes[$key]->$huidigtypeid = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: print_r($oppervlakte); and which index do u want from this array?

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly do you mean?

Comment: this line `if($oppervlakte[$value->$key == true]){` seems a bit wrong except you know what you are doing maybe it should be like this:
`if($oppervlakte[$value->$key] == true){`

Comment: foreach ($testoppervlaktes as $oppervlakte): ?>
<?php 
foreach($testtypes as $key => $value){
 print_r($oppervlakte);
}

Comment: what is it you are trying to test in that line?  what do you expect for various conditions?

Comment: Updated OP with what it is I am trying to test

Comment: Answer updated maybe it works with {$key}

Comment: I tried your updated answer and I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: ok also print_r($testtypes); check r u getting same index?

Comment: i think the problem is on `$value` so the source `$testtypes`

Comment: I did this and the id's from print_r($testtypes); are the same(4 - 5 - 6 - 7)

Comment: as result from print_r($testtypes); i get an array with 4 objects the id's are 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 so it seems ok or not?

Comment: looks fine, now echo $value->{$key}; "<br/>"; check r u getting 6 ,4

Comment: I get this error "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$0 in " on that line where I try to echo it

Comment: try isset() before the main if condition

Comment: so like this? isset($oppervlakte[$value->{$key}] == true){  ?

Comment: it doesn't change anything, same error occurs

Comment: Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be like that:

```
if($oppervlakte[$value->{$key}] == true){                       
   // your stuff
} else {               
   // your stuff    
}
```

Comment: I've tried this already, it still gives the same error, unfortunately

Comment: @FrankLucas: $key have numeric key... u cannot use it.

Comment: Do you have any idead on what should I use then?

Comment: @FrankLucas: foreach ($testoppervlaktes as $oppervlakte): ?> <?php foreach($testtypes as $key => $value){ print_r($oppervlakte); }